# prove that $\sum ^s _{r=0} \binom {n+r} r 2^{-r}=2^s$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

prove that $$\sum ^s _{r=0} \binom {n+r} r 2^{-r}=2^s$$

I am trying to prove this by using induction , but i stuck here is the my attempt can any help

[image]

Comment: I think in place of 's' it should be 'n'. Though you require proof by induction the solutions given here may interest you(You may check this out.See problem A2.https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2020.pdf). The solution is given here https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2020s.pdf

Comment: There must be an error in the equation as it is given now. For example, let $s=1$. Then the equation would say that $1+(n+1)/2=2$ for any $n$, which is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the comment of @Marveric a
slightly different solution:
To prove that $$S_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n+k \choose r} 2^{-r}=2^n$$
Re-write
$$S_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} \left({n+r-1 \choose r}+{n+r-1\choose r-1} \right)2^{-r}$$
$$\implies S_n=S_{n-1}+{2n-1 \choose n}2^{-n}+\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n+r-1 \choose r-1} 2^{-r}$$
$$\implies S_n=S_{n-1}+{2n-1 \choose n-1}2^{-n}+\sum_{=0}^{n-1} {n+s \choose s} 2^{-s-1}+{2n \choose n}2^{-n-1}-{2n \choose n}2^{-n-1}-$$
$$\implies S_n=S_{n-1}+{2n-1 \choose n-1}2^{-n}+\sum_{s=0}^{n} {n+s \choose s} 2^{-s-1}-{2n \choose n}2^{-n-1}.$$
$$\implies S_n =S_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}S_n \implies S_n=2S_{n-1} \implies S_n=2^n$$